# Transformation of an elliptical PDE

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> The object of this problem is to show that, by an appropriate transformation of variables, the general homogeneous second order partial differential equation
> $$
> a \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+2 b \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}+c \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=0
> $$
> with constant coefficients can be reduced to either Laplace's equation, the wave equation, or the heat equation.
> If $a c-b^{2}>0$, show that the substitution $s=(b x-a y) /\left(a c-b^{2}\right)^{1 / 2}, t=y$ changes
> (*) to
> $$
> \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial s^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}=0 .
> $$

(*) here refers to the equation $a \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+2 b \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}+c \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=0$.

I tried to solve this by assuming $u(s,t)=u(f(x,y))$ where $f: (x,y) \mapsto ((b x-a y) /\left(a c-b^{2}\right)^{1 / 2},y)$  and then applying chain rule. But I am not getting the right answer. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Can you show your working? Essentially your change of variable is letting $u(x,y) \to u(s(x,y),t(x,y))$ and so want to recompute derivatives as \begin{align} u_{x} &\to u_{s} s_{x} + u_{t} t_{x} & &= - \frac{b}{(ac - b^{2})^{1/2}} u_{s} + 0 \\ u_{xx} &\to u_{ss} s_{x}^{2} + u_{s} s_{xx} + u_{tt} t_{x}^{2} + u_{t} t_{xx} & &= \frac{b^{2}}{ac - b^{2}} u_{ss} + 0 + 0 + 0 \\ u_{xy} &\to u_{ss} s_{x} s_{y} + u_{s} s_{xy} + u_{tt} t_{x} t_{y} + u_{t} t_{xy} & &= \dots \end{align} and similarly for $u_{yy}$.

Comment: I am getting $u_{yy}= \frac{a^2}{ac-b^2}u_{ss}-\frac{2a}{(ac-b^2)^{1/2}}u_{st}+u_{tt}$ and $u_{yx}=  \frac{-ab}{ac-b^2}u_{ss} +  \frac{b}{(ac-b^2)^{1/2}}u_{ts}$ @mattos

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write out the full expressions above. It's hard putting bulk LaTeX in a comment. It should have been \begin{align}u_{x}&\to u_{s}s_{x}+u_{t}t_{x} \\ u_{xx}&\to u_{ss}s_{x}^{2}+u_{st}s_{x}t_{x}+u_{s}s_{xx}+u_{tt}t_{x}^{2}+u_{ts}t_{x}s_{x}+u_{t}t_{xx} \\ u_{xy} &\to u_{ss} s_{x} s_{y} + u_{st} s_{x} t_{y} + u_{s} s_{xy} + u_{tt} t_{x} t_{y} + u_{ts} t_{x} s_{y} + u_{t} t_{xy} \\ u_{yy} &\to u_{ss} s_{y}^{2} + u_{st}s_{y}t_{y}+u_{s}s_{yy}+u_{tt}t_{y}^{2}+u_{ts} t_{y} s_{y} + u_{t} t_{yy} \end{align} Now compute the derivatives as you did above and substitute into the original PDE.